# Is it possible to fetch/retrieve specific or all user's session cache details?

Tags: platform-cache

We are setting some information using the platform cache (session cache) and we are facing some issues/inconsistencies in the data.

So, it is possible to retrieve stored user session cache details without logging as a specific users. I didn't find any specific details in the documentation.

Currently, I need to log in as a specific user, enable log for that user, and test execute the operation to generate and debug the values.